# Cron job issue with indexing

Tags: cron, reindex, crontab, indexer

I have set cron for indexing issue. but i have got error in mail.

```
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 2: /backup: Is a directory
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 3: access-logs: command not found
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 4: access-logs: command not found
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 5: access-logs: command not found
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 6: access-logs: command not found
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 7: ` * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)'
```

Any Expert Please help i have try some solution but no luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633739/i-got-error-while-run-cron-job-using-php-how-to-i-fixed-it

Use:
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /path/to/the/script.php

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a syntax error in `/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php` If you look closer at your email it is trying to execute the doc comment block in the PHP file. Most probably the opening PHP tag is missing `<` sign.

```
/home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
```

-- UPDATED --

**OR**

You are trying to execute PHP file as a shell script.
Try updating your Cron job to

```
* * * * * php /home/ltfab/public_html/shell/indexer.php
```